# "I can command English."

Tags: nouns, meaning-in-context, word-usage, verbing

I saw a sentence: "I would like to be a scientist who can command English."

What do you think about usage of "command"? Should we say " ...who has a good command of English."?

Could you please explain which sentence is better? If it it wrong usage, 
tell me the reason.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: The second sentence is correct. The first is not. One does not simply **command** English :-)

Comment: Oh, Thank you very much for you quick answer! I would appriciate if you could tell me why the first one is incorrect.

Comment: What would you command English to do?

Comment: You can command English, and so can I, and so can any man; but does it obey when you command it?

Comment: It is wrong because the expression is "command of" something: Ability to control or use; mastery: _command of_ four languages.

Comment: I would add the word "language" to your second example to make it sound "better"--to my ears anyway:  "He has a good command of the English language."

Comment: To be able to command English or any other language you need to be a conjurer not a scientist :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind and humorous answers.  Kind of you to answer that basic question.

Answer (score 5):

Today the verb "command" commonly implies to most users that you would order someone to do something. Since a language like English cannot follow an order, you cannot command it.

But there is a somewhat old-fashioned, maybe obsolete use of the verb command which is reflected in this quote from Tennyson:

"My harp would prelude woe—I cannot all command the strings."

Here the meaning is control or mastery, which is [meaning III in the Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/36949). And with this meaning (which, in the OED, has been documented to be current until the mid 1800s), your phrase is certainly possible, and actually still (though rarely) in use today:

"It is easy to see that the idea of ‘knowing’ a language will be in the same trouble, as will the project of characterising the abilities or capacities a person must have if he commands a language." ~ Donald Davidson, [A nice derangement of epitaphs](http://psych.stanford.edu/~michael/papers/Davidson_Derangement.pdf)

So in fact the sentence you saw is correct.

Comment: "correct" in a technical sense, yes, but I think if you tried to use it in everyday speech you'd get odd looks.

Comment: Thank you very much for your instructive answers.   Now I feel good to know correct usage of 'command'.

Comment: @Lynn You are right. Do you feel my note that the usage is old-fashioned is enough to warn anyone of that reaction? Or do I need to spell it out?

Comment: @what - On second reading, I think you say that with your use of 'old fashioned' and 'rarely'.

Comment: What?! People didn't know this? And even think it is not quite acceptable today? The OD has not changed its entries yet, and I don't think it would any time soon. Both the OP's sentences are grammatically correct and make sense.

Comment: @Kris Well, the OED entry is from 1891, and language changes a lot in a hundred years. That entry is no longer reliable for current English usage. Merriam-Webster Online does not list this meaning, so it might in fact be obsolete or rare.

Comment: "**command** *noun* 2 [in singular] the ability to use or control something: *he had a brilliant command of English*" (http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/command) -- this is current. "5. Ability to control or use; mastery: *command of four languages.*" (AHD > http://www.thefreedictionary.com/command)

Comment: @Kris Absence from a dictionary means nothing.

Answer (score 0):

"To have a good command of English" is correct modern British usage, "to command English" is not.

SOED has "command of language", meaning "skill in speech, articulacy" (SOED noun sense 3). [Oxforddictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/command) has "he had a brilliant command of English" (noun sense 2) as an example of "the ability to use or control something".

That's using "command" as a noun, broadly meaning "mastery". You wouldn't "mastery English" (you'd "have mastery of English"), so instead of "command English" it's "have command of English".

Why it doesn't work using the verb "to command": I can command the strings of a musical instrument (although it sounds a bit archaic) because I have control over them - I can make them sound in response to my will. I can give them commands and they will act in response to those commands. I can't make the English language act in response to my will - if I tell the English language to do something, it won't - so I can't "command English".

(To "master English" is fine, by the way, although if someone *can* master English it just means they're capable of mastering it, not that they necessarily *have* mastered it).

The Davidson example (raised by user "what" in their answer), "if he commands a language", is correct (though unusual) usage but is not the same as the OP's example "a scientist who can command English".